# How do you uninstall a version of Java (e.g., openjdk 15) from MacOS?

Tags: java

I have to uninstall openjdk-15 (specifically openjdk-15.0.2) from my mac because for some reason it was failing unit tests while older versions were not.

How do I uninstall this version of java while leaving the other ones alone?

Answer (score 3):

Figure out what java versions you have running with the following command:
`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

for me this returned the following:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    15.0.2, x86_64: "OpenJDK 15.0.2"    /Users/<USER>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.2/Contents/Home
    11.0.10.1, x86_64:  "Amazon Corretto 11"    /Users/<USER>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.10/Contents/Home
    11.0.10, x86_64:    "AdoptOpenJDK 11"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then used the main directory of the folder and deleted it (e.g., openjdk-15.0.2):

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/<USER>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.2/
```

Finally I tested that another version of java was now the main java version:
`java --version`